# How would it be formatted the response array in angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

***Response from API***

```
let apiResponse=[["1","Test1","9430"],["2","Test2","1086"],["3","Test3","704"],["4","Test4","243"],["5","Test5","292"],["6","Test6","386"],["7","Test7","492"]]
```

***Formatted Array***

```
formattedArray=[[undefined, undefined, "9430", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
 [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "1086"],
[undefined, undefined, undefined, "704", undefined, undefined, undefined],
["243", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "292", undefined, undefined],
 [undefined, "386", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
 [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "492", undefined]]
```

above formatted array for my project purposes.

Comment: Why would you need such an array with too many `undefined`s and what decides the position of the number element in each sub array?

Comment: @MichaelD, this requirement for my project purpose to show the values in charts

Comment: @sankar, I tried to find by what algorithm the values ​​as you gave in the example can be set. But even after doing some work, I could not understand the algorithm, because if you take even a simple approach, then your elements are exposed according to a strange dependence. 3, 11, 4, 4, 11, 4, 11 this is if the entire array is drawn into a line, but even with this approach there is no logic.